# Does testing 'like' button linked to content on Facebook only accessible server have negative impact on domain

Tags: javascript, facebook, seo

Does anyone know if Facebook frowns upon content only they can access, meaning not publicly reachable?  I have a test server `http://test.somesite.com` with some custom JS which we implemented Facebook like buttons with.  This is where we test the development code prior to deployment to the live server at `http://www.somesite.com` so we want to have solid test coverage including these like buttons.

The server `http://test.somesite.com` is only accessible to our office and a few places outside if we open our firewall.  To get the like functionality tested, we can punch a hole in the firewall for Facebook to hit.

The problem I'm concerned with is if Facebook detects the limited content accessibility.  I'm sure they don't want to post tons of links to pages  that their users will get a 'Forbidden', other error, or timeout if they click on it.  I know Google would have a fit if they detected you doing something like this and it affected their search results...   Also, there's the concern for Duplicate content being on both `http://test.somesite.com` and `http://www.somesite.com`.

Does creating a test links like this hurt our main server or domain in Facebook searches?  I'm unfamiliar with SEO guidelines for Facebook (or if there are any yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook needs to access the og tags on the page in order for the like button to work, so if you want to test it, your site needs to be accessible. What I'd be more cautious about is repeatedly posting then deleting stories from your site in the testing. I think Facebook would take that as a signal to rank down your content.

Comment: I see your point about frequently posting and deleting stories.  By fully opening your test site, do you see the potential dangers though?  First, if you have to expose a content from test server to the world, you're creating links to content at a different domain name than the actual live content. This would create a duplicate content situation, which is a big SEO no-no.  Second it would expose your test site, which may have bugs and/or security flaws to the outside world.  Do you know any test endpoint Facebook provides to verify, but not 'really' register likes and such?

Comment: Also, if you open you test site to just facebook, I confirm they can access the OG tags.  But, if the rest of the world can't access it, when they click on the link to it from Facebook, would FB penalize that?

Comment: I don't know if what Facebook does for links to inaccessible content.

Comment: I think everything you say in your answer is correct.  The take away is don't post unreachable content or garbage to facebook.  Someone recently indicated you can set up a sandbox application with Facebook to test with--I'm going look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook doesn't have any SEO guidelines. You can test as much as you need.